# Retrieve next card(s) base on the provided parameter

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

How can I remove the duplicated `params[:next_cards]`?

```
def index
  if params[:next_cards] # check nil
    render json: current_user.next_cards(params[:next_cards].to_i),
           status: :ok
  else
    render json: current_user.cards, status: :ok
  end
end
```

Inside the `user.rb` module,

```
  def next_cards(num_of_cards=nil)
    if num_of_cards
      cards.next_cards.limit(num_of_cards)
    else
      cards.next_cards
    end
  end
```

Inside the `card.rb` module,

```
  def self.next_cards
    joins(:meta_sm2).merge(MetaSm2.next_cards).order('RANDOM()')
  end
```

Inside the `meta_sm2.rb` model,

```
  scope :next_cards, -> { where('next_repetition <= :current_time', current_time: Time.now) }
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to remove it. It all seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, in response to the conversation in comments, Here's my suggested first step:

```
  def index
    render json: cards, status: :ok
  end

  private

  def cards
    if next_cards
      current_user.next_cards(next_cards.to_i)
    else
      current_user.cards
    end
  end

  def next_cards
    params[:next_cards]
  end
```

the larger issue here though is that you are essentially using `params[:next_cards]` as a switch for what should essentially be two controller actions.  the latter being the index action of the cards controller, and the former being something along the lines of `user/next_cards/:id` . Possibly a next cards controller.  The show action of which could look something like

routes.rb:

```
resource :next_cards, only: :show
```

app/controllers/next_cards_controller.rb:

```
def show
  render json: current_user.next_cards(params[:id])
end
```

controllers don't have to have a 1 to 1 mapping with models. This way takes advantage of rails routing to validate that params[:id] will always be present. thereby eliminating the need for a nil check.

Obviously this could take more time as your views will need to be updated to reflect the new route. If it's a greenfield app, go ahead and do it right now. If it's an old, bloated codebase, start small with the refactor and do it in chunks.

Comment: I have updated the code. @chris

Comment: you're already checking for `nil` in the method. you don't need to check for it again before you call the method. simply remove the `nil` check from your controller action.

Comment: you most likely don't need the `to_i` in the controller either, which is what i assume drove the decision to put the nil check in the controller action. either move it inside `next_cards` or remove it completely.

Comment: I am doing so because if `next_cards` is `nil` the logic is different. `next_cards` return a special set of cards.

Comment: what's in the `next_cards` scope on the card model?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: updated my answer. I think I understand a little better now.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are switching on the parameter in both the `index` and the `User#next_cards` methods makes it look like one is redundant to me. It looks almost like you could remove the conditional from `index` and just change `next_cards` slightly.